# Fill table row with 3 columns with values

Tags: ios, algorithm, modulo

I have a table with 2 rows with each 3 columns in it and an Array with 5 values. These values should be displayed successively in the 3 columns, e.g.

```
indexPath.row 0: Array[0] | Array[1] | Array[2]
indexPath.row 1: Array[3] | Array[4] |
```

I want to create some coding, which puts my values (it doesn't care how much e.g. 5,6,7,...,20,21 in the format of 3 columns in rows) the rows are calculated at the size of the array with the values.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{    
    NSMutableArray *values = [... getValues];
    int no=0;
    if (values) {
        no=(values.count+1)/3;
    }
    else{
        no=0;
    }
    return no;
}
```

My current problem is, I don't get the 5 values distributed in the columns.
I'm struggeling around with the calculation, these won't fit with the index of the array ...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//order values in 3 columns and 2 rows (currently)...
}
```

BR,
mybecks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

```
NSInteger count = numberOfValues;
NSInteger start = indexPath.row * 3;
NSInteger end = MIN(start + 3, count);

for(int i = start; i < end; i++)
{
  if(i%3 == 0){//left}
  if(i%3 == 1){//center}
  if(i%3 == 2){//right}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose COLS is the number of columss, and V is the number of values, where M is the matrix, and Vector is the values vector:

```
for i = 0 to V-1:
    M[i div COLS][i mod COLS] = Vector[i]
```